# Categories with Subcategories in table - PHP + MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, categories

I have Categories and Sub-Categories on my database. Database table contain "cid" , "pid" and "cname" columns.

Cid = Categories ID

Pid = If Category is a Sub-Category , then Pid = that belong which category.

Cname = Category Name

For Example Software is a category and id = 15 and "IOS Software is a sub-category and id= 30 and pid = 15

Now I want to show this Cat. And Sub-Cat in a table. Here is my code:

```
   <?php
  function categories() {
  $categorysql = $DB['DB_Database']->query("SELECT cid, pid, cname FROM categories GROUP BY cid");
       while ($row = $DB['DB_Database']->fetch_assoc($categorysql))
      {
          if ($row['pid'] > 0 {
                      }
                       else {
                              $catid = $row['cid'];
                              $catname = $row['cname']; }
  }
```

with this code I can show only Main Categories. Sample Pics here:

[image]

But I want to show like this:

[image]

My Table Code here is like this:

```
<table width="268" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="52" rowspan="2" valign="top">Image</td>
    <td width="200" height="23"><a href="{$catid}">{$catname}<a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="36" valign="top">This ara for sub cat.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So how can I do that, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest changing your php code to work with the following sql that uses an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
select c.cname, c2.cname subname
from categories c
  left join categories c2 on c.cid = c2.pid
where c.pid is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc890/1)

This assumes the parent's pid field is null.  Alternatively you could use `GROUP_CONCAT` to return all your subcategories in a single row instead of multiple rows -- this might be easier for your implementation.

Comment: Hmm, it look little bit complicated for me. After i put this in Query , how must be rows are ?

Answer (score 1):

For easier implementation your can make two quires

This will give all the categories. ( Let say root category pid will be 0

`SELECT name FROM categories where pid = 0`

In that loop use 2nd query

```
SELECT name FROM categories where pid = $catId
```

Here is the php code example to populate the array you can use

function runQuery($sql)
    {

```
    global $DB;
    $dbResource = $DB['DB_Database']->query($sql);
    $rows = array();
    while ($row = $DB['DB_Database']->fetch_assoc($dbResource))
    {
         $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}

function getSubCat($pid)
{
    subCategorySql = "SELECT name FROM categories where pid = "+ $pid; 
    return runQuery($subCategorySql);
}

$categorySql = "SELECT name FROM categories where pid = 0"
$categories = runQuery(categorySql)
$i=0;
foreach($categories as $aCat)
{
    $categories[$i++]['sub_cat'] = getSubCat($aCat['id']);
}
```

now you can use $categories[index]['name'] for category and $categories[index]   ['sub_cat'][sub_cat_index][name] for subcategory name.

This is not a good approach though as it will hit database so many time.