# category and subcategroy in same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to create a table for category and subcategory in the same table.My table format will be as following:

```
Id       Title           Parent id
1.       Spain           None
2.       Barcelona       1
3.       India            None
4.       Delhi           3
```

Please give me mysql query for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a normal table in which the value of parent ID would be `zero` (0) for top level entities.

You may also keep the column `nullable` by having `NULL` for top level entities.

I would recommend to use zero for type safety.

> Please use this as a starting point and not as a copy paste solution.

Comment: You may use mysqldump, phpMyAdmin or similar tools to create script to create the table.

Answer (score 0):

i think question already asked on stack overflow please refer this link

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892855/categories-with-subcategories-in-table-php-mysql)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516834/mysql-categories-and-subcategories-listing)

The first thing that you should do is read this article at mysql.com.
[Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
 or [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101023153136/http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

i hope this reference give you your solution.